# Huge number of session files in tomcat running wicket application

Tags: session, tomcat6, diskspace, wicket-1.5

I am running an wicket 1.5.7 application on `Tomcat 6` and `CentOS`. Last 7 days I have a **huge** number of **session** folders in tomcat work folder. Those folders doesn't get **deleted** after session has expired. If I take a look a folder last update date, it seems like new session is created every 10 secs, which should not be like that if I take a look a traffic. That is causing my disk very quickly becomes full.All pages are state-full and for most of them I am using

```
public class MountedMapperWithoutPageComponentInfo extends MountedMapper {
public MountedMapperWithoutPageComponentInfo(String mountPath, Class<? extends IRequestablePage> pageClass) {
        super(mountPath, pageClass, new PageParametersEncoder());
      }
      @Override
      protected void encodePageComponentInfo(Url url, PageComponentInfo info) {
        // do nothing so that component info does not get rendered in url
      }
      @Override 
      public Url mapHandler(IRequestHandler requestHandler) 
      { 
          if (requestHandler instanceof ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler) { 
              return null; 
          } else { 
               return super.mapHandler(requestHandler); 
          } 
      }
```

in order not to have version number in URL.

Any idea?